# Rails server command generates another folder in project's folder with default folders and files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

![Here is the screenshot of what rails server command is doing, instead of setting rails server... ][1]

Please see this what's happening and try to help me...  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSh21.png

Comment: Whats the output if you type the full command "rails server"? Have you done "bundle install" etc?

Comment: Why are you using Rails 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using rails 2 gem version, you can check by `rails -v`. As well you can see, there is no app/assets folder. there are only public/javascripts etc rails2 style directories

Try to install rails 3 by

```
gem install rails  --version '>3.0.0'
```